# Salesforce - how to pass specific value in apex:repeat to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, parameter-passing, visualforce, repeat

Is there a client-side way of passing a value from within an apex:repeat to a javascript function?

Basically, my list is iterated, with each unique itemLat / itemLon, and I'd need to pass the specific lat/lon back to a javascript function for some processing. Any ideas on how to approach this?

The reason I'd want to do this is because I have a separate JS function that does some JS remoting, so ideally, i'd like to just pass the new params to that function so it can do it's work in the controller, but with the new lat/lon as the starting parameters.

```
   <apex:repeat var="frm" id="searchResult" value="{!newSearchList}">
     <div id="search-item">
       <p style="font-size:12px">
         <apex:outputLink value="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setCoords(itemLat, itemLon);" id="itemLink">
         <b>{!frm.Customer_gne__r.Name}</b>
           <apex:param name="itemLat" value="{!frm.Test_Lat__c}"/>
           <apex:param name="itemLon" value="{!frm.Test_Lon__c}"/>
         </apex:outputLink><br/>
         {!frm.Primary_Address_gne__r.Name}, {!frm.Primary_Address_gne__r.City_vod__c}<br/>
         {!frm.Primary_Address_gne__r.Phone_vod__c}<br/>
       </p>
     </div>
   </apex:repeat>

  function setCoords(passedLat,passedLon) {
    alert("testing the alert!" + passedLat + "    " + passedLon);
  }
```

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions, thanks: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2227/how-to-pass-specific-value-in-apexrepeat-to-a-javascript-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a normal way:

`onclick="setCoords('{!frm.Test_Lat__c}', '{!frm.Test_Lon__c}');"`

Comment: yep, I knew there was some simple way that I was missing. Javascript isn't my strong suit, and I had forgotten we can pull in repeated values like that.